# fit and fit_generator of keras are still different when I shuffle my data

Tags: keras

Keras 2.2.4 with TensorFlow on ubuntu16.04, 2080 GPU:

I get different convergence characteristics from `fit` vs `fit_generator`, `fit` converges to a reasonable solution, but `fit_generator` val loss does not.

I try to shuffle my data by [keras issues 2389](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2389),but it didn't help anything.

My code

```py
tmp = m1.fit_generator(train_it,
                       steps_per_epoch=b_iter,
                       epochs=1,
                       shuffle=True,
                       validation_data=(val_it),#validation_enter code
                       heresteps=val_batch_size
                       ,max_queue_size=batch_size
                       ,workers=5
                       , use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Train_it and val_it shuffle data in each epoch.

```py
self.a_fnames = sorted(os.listdir(self.a_dir))
np.random.shuffle(self.a_fnames)
```

Here is my train loss and val loss from `fit` vs `fit_generator`

[image]

Now I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please don't include random snippets of code in your question, a self-contained example that reproduces the problem is much better, specially as we don't know what your generator does.